# Android - Block (Prevent) user from mute a specific app

Tags: android, volume, mute

I am working on corporate app which will be installed in each of the company owned android devices.

The app should start some alert sound when the device is leaving the Wi-Fi range of the company.

The requirement is that user won't be able to mute or volume-down this application.

Is there is any way to block volume changes for specific application in android?

Comment: This is going to be funny shoud there ever be a malfunction of the company WiFi.

Comment: I think you should look into AudioManager, for managing audio stream volumes, audio ducking, and
other system-wide audio.